# a value of type "char (*)[11]" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "char *"

Tags: c, char

Вообщем, я писал задачу на C для решения задачи: "Выделить место для матрицы размерностью 3 x N (N >10 объявить как макроконстанту или константу языка С), элементы которой являются однобайтовыми числами. Первую и вторую строки матрицы заполнить случайными числами из
диапазона 0..6, первые элементы этих строк должны быть нулями. Сформированные
строки представляют собой симметричные коды двух целых чисел. Третью строчку нужно заполнить
семерными цифрами суммы этих чисел. Результат подать в качестве добавления чисел в
столбик."
Вот написаный мной код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define N 11
int main(void) {
    char matr[3][N] = { {},{},{} }, i, j,*prow;
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (i = 1; i < N; i++) {
        matr[0][i] = rand() % 7;
    }
    for (i = 1; i < N; i++) {
        matr[1][i] = rand() % 7;
    }
    for (i = N-1; i > 0; i--) {
        char sum;
        sum = matr[0][i] + matr[1][i] + matr[2][i];
        matr[2][i] = sum % 7;
        matr[2][i - 1] = sum / 7;
    }
    for (prow = matr; prow < matr + 3; prow++) {
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
            printf("%u", *(*prow + j));
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Когда я писал без указателей, только через индексную форму обращения к елементам, всё работало. Но мне надо впихнуть указатели, ведь такови условия написания лаборатоной роботы. Помогите мне решить ету проблему, пожалуйста!

Comment: Рассматривайте матрицу как одномерный массив. Моделируется указателем, скажем `char *a;` на `matr[0][0]`. Доступ к i,j-му элементу -- `a[i * N + j]` (N -- количество элементов в строке)

Comment: Так сделайте как сказано — выделите место для нее в памяти динамически, и все сразу станет на свои места...